# How can I increase tracking speed of Macbook Trackpad beyond the maximum (Sierra<)?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, trackpad, preferences

**How can I increase tracking speed of Macbook Trackpad beyond the maximum?**

The MacOS maximum trackpad tracking speed is extremly slow.
Since Sierra it seems like it's not possible to change the Macbook Trackpad tracking speed beyond maximum.
I tried the following but it didn't work:

- changing tracking speed with **BetterTouchTool** doesnt work since El
  Capitan.
- Changing

  `~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist`

  with terminal comand

  `defaults write -g com.apple.trackpad.scaling -float 8.0`

  or any other number higher than 3.0 doesn't change anything.

Pls help I can't use trackpad this slow, because moving my finger too much on the trackpad makes my finger sore and hurts (maybe I have some kind of allergy to MBP 2015 trackpad).